# DocumentDB 'all/any' functionality

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Imagine I have the data in Cosmos

```
[
    {
        "id": "FCEC01CD-A6E9-4DEA-8DD5-89711B5B05A1",
        "sub": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "v": false
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "v": false
            }
        ]
]
```

and I want to query for all id's that have all (sibbeling) 'sub' items having v=false
what query syntax would work?
(ARRAY_CONTAINS would not work, since that gives an 'any' result)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a user-defined function for this.

```
function arrayAllMatch(arr) {
  for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].v === true) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Then call within query (also include ARRAY_CONTAINS because it can use the index to reduce the number of calls to the UDF):

```
SELECT * 
FROM c 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.sub, {"v" : false }, true) 
AND udf.arrayAllMatch(c.sub)
```

Comment: Thanks, this certainly would work. But not for my dynamic CosmosDB SQL generator, that might not have the authorization to upload an udf to Cosmos
(at nuget ADCCure.Azure.Documents.OData.Sql)